# How to programatically copy script permissions for a file bound script in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-script-api

I'm trying to implement a performance evaluation system using google sheets + forms. Overall, what I need to do is generate a form for each user, according to a template. After the user has submitted an answer, I need to edit the form, in order to remove one of the options, avoiding duplicate submissions by my coworkers.

In order to achieve that, I intended to create the forms and link them to the same Spreadsheet sheet - and, as far as I could understand, that is not possible. Therefore, having my forms submitting data to the same place is not feasible using the standard flow, since I'd need to create about 100 tabs in my spreadsheet, each one containing around 7, 8 rows (which would not be entered at once, but gradually, in each spreadsheet).

Anyway, my last idea was not to link any of the forms to my spreadsheet, but rather write a simple script in the template form to write that data in my Spreadsheet. That script is bound to the forms, and, therefore, when I copy the template and create a new form, the script gets copied as well. That worked finely, but, for every new copy, I need to manually grant permissions for the script (it needs to write on my responses Spreadsheet).

The most simple solution for me would be able to write the results of all forms in the same spreadsheet (being able to act on each of the forms submissions separately), but I'm afraid that won't be possible. Therefore, is it at all possible to copy a bound to file project and its permissions altogether, so that it won't require manual granting?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible. Perhaps the [forms service api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) has some hints?

Comment: @jspcal I've read most of it, if not all, and can't find anything related to permissions. I've been actually thinking of going down to Google Apps Script REST API, but then again, to use it, I'd need URLFetch method, which also requires authorization (and, as far as I know, it's not even allowed for bound scripts anyway)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a Google web app, and making your own interface instead of a Google Form?  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Oh, thanks for the suggestion, I hadn't really given this a thought before. I'll try to avoid it, though, because my ~ abilities ~ with HTML are far below lackluster, and I was hoping to avoid going trough that hassle.

Comment: Comming back here to accept your suggestion. I ended up doing just that - given I'm a complete novice in web programming, knowing very little of HTML, even less of CSS, it has been troublesome, but I got it done following this suggestionn and the final result has been quite satisfying.